# Copy to Clipboard Italics in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, methods

I have figured out how to copy text to clipboard using React, but I want this.state.parties to be italicized and this.state.citation not to be italicized when I paste them.  I am able to render to the screen the proper italicized form by using `<i>` tags.

```
  handleCopyCitation = () => {
    let textField = document.createElement('textarea')
    let citationText = this.state.parties + this.state.citation
    textField.innerText = citationText.italics()
    document.body.appendChild(textField)
    textField.select()
    document.execCommand('copy')
    textField.remove()
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

Your problem stems from the fact that `<textarea>` elements can only hold *plain text*; and no formatted elements. To apply formatting to the text within a `<textarea>`, you can use CSS, but it effects the whole field and also will not be copied.

Luckily, HTML5 has a solution to this problem: `contenteditable` elements. In HTML5, you can make any element `contenteditable`, which means that users can edit its contents - this is used to build stuff like WYSIWYG editors. `contenteditable` elements support *rich text*, which means that any HTML can be put inside of them; **and copied richly.**

Therefore, if you have a hidden `contenteditable` element, you can set its contents to be whatever text you want to be copied (this can be any string, and can contain HTML), focus the element, select its text, and then copy it.

It should be a hidden element, rather than one you make on the fly, as unlike with a `<textarea>` some of these actions take a little bit more time and might not be completed before the elements removal. This can be resolved by only removing the element after a set amount of time, but this time varies between computers and can make the element flash on the screen. Actually hidden elements (e.g. with CSS like `visiblity:hidden` or `display:none`) can't be focused, so a nice solution is to instead position the element far off of the screen.

From there, and with a reference to the element's DOM node, `.innerHTML` can set the text content (e.g. what you want to copy), `.focus()` focuses the element, `document.execCommand("selectAll")` selects the text (note `.select()` doesn't exist for `contenteditable` elements), and finally `document.execCommand("copy")` copies the text.

Here's a working example. As a test it copies a string which contains bold formatting, italic formatting and colour, but I'm sure you can adapt it to your needs.

```js
function handleCopyCitation(citationText) {
  let copyArea = document.getElementById("copyArea");
  copyArea.innerHTML = citationText;
  copyArea.focus();
  document.execCommand("selectAll");
  document.execCommand("copy");
}

function test() {
  handleCopyCitation("<strong>Hello, </strong><em><span style=\"color:red;\">world!</span></em>");
}
```

```css
#copyArea {
  position:fixed;
  left:-10000px;
  top:-10000px;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="test()">Copy Text</button>

<div id="copyArea" contenteditable="true"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you!  The only substantive change I made was to change the call to handleCooyCitation in test() to a template string so I could reference this.state.parties and this.state.citation.  The styling shows up when pasted.  Thanks again for your thorough explanation.